# Incremental hash calculation

Tags: java, hash

```
  MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     String s = "" + i;
     byte[] bs = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
     md5.update(bs);

     String currMd5 = ...;
     System.out.println(currMd5);
  }
```

As per Javadocs:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html#digest()

> public byte[] digest()
>   Completes the hash computation by performing final operations such as padding. **The digest is reset after this call is made.**

so that cannot be used.

Is it possible to somehow produce `currMd5` above after each call to `update`, i.e. incrementally based on all input so far? Using MD5 is not a constraint, i.e. any reasonable hash should work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one solution seems to be to clone:

```
  MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     String s = "" + i;
     byte[] bs = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
     md5.update(bs);

     MessageDigest md5c = (MessageDigest) md5.clone(); 

     byte[] bytes = md5c.digest();
     String currentMd5 = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(bytes);
     System.out.println("md5: " + currentMd5);
  }
```

which produces:

```
md5: CFCD208495D565EF66E7DFF9F98764DA
md5: 96A3BE3CF272E017046D1B2674A52BD3
md5: D2490F048DC3B77A457E3E450AB4EB38
md5: EB62F6B9306DB575C2D596B1279627A4
md5: 4100C4D44DA9177247E44A5FC1546778
md5: D6A9A933C8AAFC51E55AC0662B6E4D4A
md5: 124BD1296BEC0D9D93C7B52A71AD8D5B
md5: 2E9EC317E197819358FBC43AFCA7D837
md5: 22975D8A5ED1B91445F6C55AC121505B
md5: 781E5E245D69B566979B86E28D23F2C7
```

I hope there are better solutions though, not liking cloning that much...